# iOS push notifications with Xamarin.iOS not showing up consistently

Tags: c#, xamarin, push-notification, xamarin.ios

We've been trying to get iOS push notifications to work but it's been very inconsistent. We've created a test project with as little code as possible just to get notifications to work.

We decided to test with alert notifications since we couldn't even get that to work consistently.

This is what we've been doing in the FinishedLaunching method of the AppDelegate:

```
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.Delegate = this;

            var authOptions = UNAuthorizationOptions.Alert | UNAuthorizationOptions.Badge | UNAuthorizationOptions.Sound;
            UNUserNotificationCenter.Current.RequestAuthorization(authOptions, (granted, error) =>
            {
                LogInformation("RequestAuthorization", $"Granted: {granted}, Error: {error}");
                if (granted)
                    InvokeOnMainThread(UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications);
            });
```

And we log the registration token of the device in the console so that we can use that to send notifications.

```
    public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
        LogInformation("RegisteredForRemoteNotifications", "init");
        var token = ExtractToken(deviceToken);
        LogInformation("RegisteredForRemoteNotifications", token);
    }
```

That's basically all we have in the app for now.
We use the notification token in a test app to send notifications to that specific device.
These are our results:

**Use case 1**

1. Restart device
2. Send notification to device

   **Result:** Notification shows up and all new notifications keep working too.

**Use case 2**

1. Restart device
2. Send notification to device

   **Result:** Notification is not shown and no matter how often you send the notification, it won't be shown.

**Use case 3**

1. Restart device
2. Send notification to device
3. Notification is not shown.
4. Restart device

   **Result:** Notification shows up and all new notifications keep working too.

**Use case 4**

1. Restart device
2. Start application once
3. Put app in background, or close it completely
4. Send notification to device

   **Result:** Notification is shown and all new notifications keep working too.

So it looks like that once we receive 1 notification, all future notifications will work too up until the device is restarted.
After restarting the device, it's basically a coinflip: You either are lucky and receive a notification and all future notifications. Or you don't receive anything at all.

We want to receive notifications consistently and are trying to figure out how to get this done and we hope someone can shed some light into this matter.

Thanks in advance.

**Notes**

- We're using a 6th gen iPad with iOS 13.5.1
- iPad is WiFi only
- We've got a stable WiFi and internet connection

Comment: Hi please go through the link https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/150826/how-can-i-implement-push-notification-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: @Anand I fail to see how that helps me. Can you help me out here?

Comment: After restarting device and app opened, did you getting notifications?